# Why is the return type of method not included in the method-signature?

Tags: java

Why does return type of method not included in signature?

An example

```
public void method1(String arg){...}

public String method1(String arg){...}
```

It will cause an error.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is done because the compiler would not be able to figure out the overload in **all contexts**.

For example, if you call

```
String x = method1("aaa");
```

the compiler knows that you are looking for the second overload. However, if you call

```
method1("aaa");
```

like this, the compiler has no idea which one of the two methods you wanted to invoke, because it is OK to call a method returning `String` and discard the result. To avoid ambiguities like this, Java prohibits overloads that differ solely on the return type.

Answer (score 10):

Since your question doesn't address any particular programming language in the title (I know it does in the tag) I'll share my recent experience with **Swift**. 
In **Swift** function/method signature actually includes return type. So compiler throws an error only if you call this function/method without explicitly specifying return type, e.g.:

```
func some() -> Bool {
    return true;
}

func some() -> Int {
    return 1;
}

let valBool: Bool = some()
let valInt: Int = some()

// this doesn't work: Ambiguous use of 'some'
some()
```

On top of this Swift even makes it more interesting. It allows you to have 2 functions/methods with the same parameters and return types only if parameters names are different, e.g.:

```
func some(#foo: Bool) -> Bool {
    return foo;
}

func some(#bar: Bool) -> Bool {
    return bar;
}

some(foo: true)
some(bar: false)
```

Thus it gives you **semantic differentiation** in methods signature

UPD. Since Swift 2.0 external parameter name was changed and now you have to provide external and local names twice even if it's the same

```
func some(foo foo: Bool) -> Bool {
    return foo;
}

func some(bar bar: Bool) -> Bool {
    return bar;
}

some(foo: true)
some(bar: false)
```

Comment: +1 for broader then java perspective. It would be interesting to hear your opinion on whether the accuired convenience outweights the problems associated with this choice. I guess for simple return types  that does not matter much, but for objects this could allow reuse of the output variable resources... and then not letting you easily ignore return value I see as a feature not a hussle.

Answer (score 3):

You can't overload a method only on it's return type. It's simply illegal. Let's assume for a moment that overloading methods using return type would be legal and you defined two `method1` methods. Now we want to call that which returns the `String object`:

`String string = method1(sth);`

The JVM theoretically would be able to recognize which method you inteded to call, but what about such call:

`method1(sth);`

As you can see both methods could be invoked and such operations is unambiguous. The JVM doesn't know which method it should call. This is why such overloading is forbidden.

Comment: You can't because you can't? Really?

Comment: I explained that in edit ;) I submited short post because writing answers to such simple questions is like a race, so if you can please remove your vote down.

Comment: I told you why it's forbidden and such code doesn't compile. The biggest problem is with executing such unambiguos code so the language specification says that such constructions are not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is impossible to resolve which of the overloaded methods should be called in a case like this:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    method1("aaa");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several points to consider when designing things like overload resolution.

Reasons to omit overloading on return type:

1. Simplify ignoring the function return value (like people often do with the error codes).
2. Makes program easier to digest for human readers. In particular, that is the reason in Python they do not have function overloads at all. (matter of taste)
3. C legacy. When language comes from C-family and designers do not consider something to be a big deal it is left as it has always been...

Reasons to add overloading on return type:

1. Make it difficult to ignore returned values. This may be convenient and saves some typing, but will definitely bite you one day.
2. Expressivness (of course as opposed to ease of digesting :)). Did you ever wanted to write things like `int x = json.get("int_value"); float y = json.get("float_value");`? In some languages (like C++) that is still possible to achieve with proxies and cast operators, but overload on return type would be so much easier.
3. Expressiveness. Every time you pass retun value as a reference to your function just to reuse its resources this could be an overload on return type (with like hidden parameter). Consider `string s; getline(cin, s);` vs `string s = getline(cin);`. And this is where expressiveness comes together with referential transparency, and eventually, ease of code digesting.

Now back to your question 'why?'. Since you were asking about Java, the answer is obviously because James valued reasons to omit return type overloads over the reasons to include them in the language.

Answer (score 1):

I had this very same question myself at one point, and while I can see how the compiler wouldn't know which function to call when you don't assign the return value to a variable of the appropriate type, why throw the error at the function level?  Why not at the point the function(s) are called?  Basically, once you've committed to having the signature differ only by the return value, it's up to you to make sure you use them that way, and then, and only then, would the compiler complain.  Of course, it may take some extra work to get this to work with a strict one-pass compiler, but I think it could fly.

Answer (score 0):

you can call function as procedure: `method1("arg");` where method1 is the second method in your list (`String method1(String arg){}`). Compiler then would be unable to distinguish it from the first one (`void method1(String arg){}`).

Answer (score 0):

Compiler takes care of method binding. When ever it encounters methodName() it has to bind to some method definition, at that point it may not know the return type of method. So method return type is not included in the method signature. Compiler binds the method according to the method signature.

Answer (score 0):

When compiler encounters the method call. It statically binds the method call to one of the methods defined.
Lets see what happens if the return type is included in the method signature

```
class Example{
    public void method1(String arg){ return arg} 
    public String method1(String arg){}
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Example e = new Example();
        e.method1("abc");   
     }  
}
```

**e.method1("abc")**  The compiler will not know which method to bind to if return type is included in the method signature.

Answer (score -1):

Method overloading is checked on the basis of number and type of arguments not on the basis of return type. That's why you are getting the error.

Comment: Because it is an attempt to define two methode with same signature.which is being checked in methode table and it is not allowed.

Comment: Because when compiler finds two methode definition with same signature in a class then it can not distinguished which one is being kept in methode table and generates error.As i think you very well know it is not possible to declare two field with same name in a common scope..