# Why doesn't the signature of a method contain the return type?

Tags: java, methods

Let's say you have an overloaded method. Would the signature contain the return type? If not, why?

Comment: Give a sample method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the return type of method not included in the method-signature?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314316/why-is-the-return-type-of-method-not-included-in-the-method-signature)

Answer (score 3):

The signature doesn't contain a return type. **Why?** I will give some examples: let's say you have two methods:

```
int someMethod(int x) {...}

double someMethod(double x) {...}
```

If you tried to call that method as

```
System.out.println(someMethod(10));
```

the parameter types will be evaluated to call the correct method. Now let's say you have:

```
int someMethod(int x) {...}

double someMethod(int x) {...}
```

when you call it as `someMethod(10)`, Java won't know what method to call. This is why what matters is the list of parameters and not the return type.

Comment: This Java behaviour isn't very flexible, see my example from Swift language in the neighbouring topic http://stackoverflow.com/a/28079432/407986

Answer (score 1):

From [Oracle Definition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

> Definition: Two of the components of a method declaration comprise the
>   method signature—the method's name and the parameter types.

Then Method signature contains method name and parameter list **only** not the return type.

```
public             String         myMethod(String myInput)

^access modifier   ^return type   {^method name    ^parameter list}
```

inside `{ }` part is the method signature.

Comment: Yes. My question is why doesn't the method signature contain the return type? Isn't that an integral part of the method?

Comment: @priya No. method signature doesn't contains return type

Comment: @priya it is the design of Java.

Answer (score 0):

In the concept of method overloading return type  is doens'nt matter at all. Method name must  be same. That's it.

Both the methods may or not have a return type or any one method may void.