# What is the profit from ignoring return types in method signature definition?

Tags: c#, .net, overloading

[MSDN Signatures and overloading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691131(v=vs.71).aspx) contains the following definition of method signature:

> The signature of a method consists of the name of the method and the
>   type and kind (value, reference, or output) of each of its formal
>   parameters, considered in the order left to right. ***The signature of a
>   method specifically does not include the return type***, nor does it
>   include the params modifier that may be specified for the right-most
>   parameter.

What I expected to see is that method signature should have included the return type, but it does not.

What is the profit from ignoring (not including) return types into the definition of method signature? Could you please provide an example.

Comment: How would you determine which method to call in this case: `var result = GiveMeSomething();` where we have two methods like: `public static int GiveMeSomething()` and `public static string GiveMeSomething()`? Only difference is the return type (of course this results in a compilation error). Also check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314316/why-is-the-return-type-of-method-not-included-in-the-method-signature

Comment: Ask **only one question per question** please.

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi, you have posted the right answer to the first question. :)

Answer (score 1):

This might be partially incorrect, and I'm sure that this holds only a part of a complete answer, but let's see if I can clarify at least a part of it. Since you asked a whole lot of questions, I'll try to answer most.

1. You can't ignore the return type of a method.
   -Each and every time you define a method, you must define a return type (excluding anonymous methods, which this does not concern). You will always start your method definition as `void`, `string`, `int` or something.
2. Override doesn't equal overload.
   -Overloading a method means that you can specify **the same** method with differrent versions. Let's say you have a method that returns the sum of two integers. You could define the following method:

   ```
   public int Sum()
   {
       return 1 + 1;
   }
   ```

   You could overload this method by stating another *method signature* that takes in a parameter to make the method work in a slightly different way, say:

   ```
   public int Sum(int a)
   {
       return 1 + a;
   }
   ```

   Here, you would have two different signatures for a method, that you could call in a different way.
   Overriding a method would mean you change the behaviour of a method to a completely new one. Say my base class would have and *overridable* method:

   ```
   public int Sum()
   {
       return 1 + 1;
   }
   ```

   Overriding this would mean something like:

   ```
   public override int Sum()
   {
       return 1 - 1;
   }
   ```

   Overriding means that you take the place of the original method *with the same signature*.
3. Yes, it would be. As you can only define one method with the same signature.
   The thing you must understand about method signature and return type is that they don't correlate. Consider the following methods:

   ```
   public int Sum(int a)
   {
       return 1 + a;
   }
   public int Sum(string a)
   {
       int b = int.Parse(a);
       return 1 + b;
   }
   ```

   These methods have **the same return type, but different signature** since they accept different parameters. The first one takes an integer, the second a string value. Yet they produce the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it doesn't. Methods signature involves only the method name, parameters, whether `ref`/`out` and it doesn't include the return type.

Overload, resolution happens based on method signature and so having two methods like below are not overloaded at all since they just differ by return types.

```
public void foo(int data) {};

public int foo(int data) {};
```

Comment: Additionally the two together in the same class would not compile, as they have the same name and method signature - there's no way to specify "which one" the caller wants to invoke

Answer (score 0):

> What is the profit from ignoring return types? Could you please provide an example.

I'm not sure that this wouldn't be opinion based, but providing method overloads in the end should be accomplishing "the same thing", just with different inputs.  The return type of a method shouldn't change, otherwise they probably shouldn't have the same name, right?

> Are the terms "overloading" and "overriding" related?

`overloading` is providing new method signatures in order to accomplish the same goal.

Overloading example:

```
public string AddTotesToInput(string input)
{
    return string.format("totes {0}", input);
}

public string AddTotesToInput(int input)
{
    return string.format("totes {0}", input.ToString());
}
```

Note the above, they're doing the same thing but with a different method signature.

`overriding` is providing new implementation to an existing method signature.

Example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual string AddTotesToInput(string input)
    {
        return string.format("totes {0}", input);
    }
}

public class NewFoo : Foo
{

    // requirements changed, and now we need "totes mcgotes" on new implementations of the Foo class
    public override string AddTotesToInput(string input)
    {
        return string.format("totes mcgotes {0}", input);
    }        

}
```

> Is the term "method signature" related to "overriding" as well?

I guess?  You're overriding a specific method signature, so they would have to be related right?

> Should the definition of "method signature" include the return type?

No, but again, seems like a matter of opinion.

To take a bit from @Rahul's answer consider if you had a class like:

```
// Note that it's not possible for this to compile as they have the same name and method signature
public class Foo
{
    public void foo(int data) {};

    public int foo(int data) {};
}
```

as a consumer of this class, how would i specify which is being called?

Example:

```
public void DoStuff()
{
    int testData = 5;
    Foo f = new Foo();
    f.foo(testData);  // which one would get called?
}
```

There is a reason it was written the way it was :)